# Parse out unneeded data using xpath

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape a website.  After I access that website I need to get the id value of each category and use that value to redirect to the JSON web page where the data I need to scrape is.  In the image below is a partial snapshot of the HTML code showing the categories along with their value id number that I need. I need that id value so I can plug it into the end of this url and redirect to that url. "http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id="  And I need to do that for all the categories. I have the code I got so far below but right now using xpath to get those ids but it is returning the entire list of Id's at once instead of one at a time.  Pus it gives me other data I do not need.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syy7D.png)

[Currently what I am receiving for category_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UiMY.png)

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import NameItem

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "LoginSpider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formcss='#existing_users form',
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'email@example.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'passowrd'},
        callback=self.after_login
        )



    def after_login(self, response):
        item = NameItem()
        category_id = response.xpath('//*[@id="bl-category-options"]/option/@value')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
for catetegory_id in response.xpath('//select[@id="bl-category-options"]/option/@value').getall():
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url="http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id={category_id}".format(category_id=category_id),
        callback=self.parse_json_response,
    )
```